# Laravel Passport throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException exception when I try to access my routes via Insomnia REST API

Tags: laravel, routes

This has happened way too often. I've cleared my local database by running `php artisan migrate:fresh` and after that, `php artisan passport:install --force`. For some obscure reason, I'm having this infernal error

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

when I try to access my `auth:api` routes only, since **registration and login work**.

These are my routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('me', 'Api\UserController@details');
    Route::get('profile/{username}', 'Api\UserController@getUsername');
    Route::post('profile/{username}/trust', 'Api\TrustController@trust');
});

Route::post('register', 'Api\UserController@register')->name('register');
Route::post('login', 'Api\UserController@login')->name('login');
```

I am absolutely sure I am sending a `GET` request.

[image]

I know that this happens when I am not properly logged in, in other words, giving a correct token to the API, which is not the case now because I have logged in normally, and pasted the token in the header as usual.

What else? Before I refreshed my database it was working. After the refresh, this has started. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are sending this request laravel thinks that you are sending a web request instead of api request.

In order for laravel to know that its a api request set the headers:

> Content-Type : application/json
>   Accept: application/json

On your postman request. Since based the 1 flag on your header I cann see that your headers are not set correctly.

Comment: Adding the Accept header at least makes it say user is not authenticated, but it is odd because I have always done it like this, until that base refresh.

Comment: @gamofe well that is another question your error with httpnotallowed is gone so please mark the answer as correct and post the new one .